# Want to detect the user redirect from tiktok

Tags: php

I want to track users from TikTok. I want to check using `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` but i not anything on this. I can track other such as facebook, pinterest, linkedin but i can't get track tiktok. Is there any other way to detect users that comes from tiktok.

I have tried

$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']

Comment: `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` is not a safe way to check if the user came from _anywhere_, since the client can change it as they wish

Comment: Is there any other way to do this.

Comment: @SureshChand: Yes, but are you an online stalker of your users? Why not ask them kindly as every one else would do, and they may tell you if they wish.

Comment: add get parameter to the link you provide for your users, use that as identification from where they come from